# Sort by sum and chop a list of tuples in Python

Tags: list, sorting, sum, tuples

For example I need the list = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4)] to come out sorted by the sum of each tuple eg [(0, 0),(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1),(0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 4), (1, 4)].

The order of (1,1) vs (0,2) does not matter, however the tuples will be of varying but equal length.

And then chop the list down to only tuples which add up to 4 or less. eg
[(0, 0),(1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1),(0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 4)]

The order of sorting and then chopping is not necessary but the outcome should be the same if done by chopping and then sorting.

Comment: That's very simple to do in many languages. What are you using, and what have you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry I am using python, should have said that.

Comment: `sorted((x for x in lst if sum(x) <= 4), key=lambda x: sum(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
list.sort(key=sum)
while sum(list[-1])>4:
    list.pop()
```

Little late but for everybody reading this later.